# Java- What is the best way to search for the last occurrence of an element in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, big-o, binary-search

I am writing this method :
    findLastOccurrence(Object item) {}

to find the index just after the last occurrence of item in a sorted array of objects. This method is part of a larger data structure that passes a comparator in for a parameter, so the objects are always comparable. I want to do this in the most efficient way possible, but I'm not sure if a linear method or a method using binary search would be faster. If anyone could show me their recommended implementation of this method it would be much appreciated.

Comment: The best way is to first write code that attempts to solve this *before* coming to stackoverflow, and then if that didn't work, posting your attempt on stackoverflow with your question. Hint, use a for loop that starts at the end of the array and loops towards the beginning.

Comment: `but I'm not sure if a linear method or a method using binary search would be faster` Why not? Do you understand what a binary search does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the kind of the data in the array. If the items are often repeating and more likely to have the last occurrence on (array.length - log_2(array.length)) position or closer to the end - linear search will be better. Otherwise - use binary search.

Additionally you could consider data locality - binary search requires access to random elements in the array and can access more cache lines than linear search - but it also depends on the kind of data you want to store there.

If you're not sure - use binary search.

Edit:
Actually after thinking more about this question linear search (step=1) would be worse than a search with step increasing after each iteration - like binary search run backwards - check elements: (n-1)-1, (n-1)-(1+2),(n-1)-(1+2+4), ... (n-1)-(2^k) and if smaller is found run a binary search between (n-1)-(2^k) and (n-1)-(2^(k-1)).